# Animation on text expanding and background color

Tags: javascript, css

I have to need animation or transition on expanding text and background colour similar like this design

When I click on ***read more*** button, text expand without animations, it would be better if i can transitions on background colour .

**Screenshot**
[image]

And here is my *CODE* for reference

```js
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("mgh-btn");
var myFunction = function() {
  this.classList.add("clicked");
  this.previousElementSibling.classList.remove("text-matter");
  for (let i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    if (classname[i] != this) {
      classname[i].classList.remove("clicked");
    }
    if (classname[i].previousElementSibling != this.previousElementSibling) {
      classname[i].previousElementSibling.classList.add("text-matter");
    }
  }
};

for (let i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
  classname[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
}
```

```css
.mgh-std-com-area {
  margin: 80px 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* .mgh-std-com-sitem:hover {
  background: #eef9f9;
} */


/* .mgh-std-com-sitem:hover > .mgh-sc-box {
  background: #ffffff;
} */

.mgh-std-com-sitem .mgh-sc-box {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #eef9f9;
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem .mgh-sc-box img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem h5 {
  color: #2f2f2f;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: calc(22px + (30 - 22) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem h5::after {
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #349dcd;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem p {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #2f2f2f;
  font-size: calc(16px + (22 - 16) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
}

.mgh-btn {
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #50c1c4, #349dcd);
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.9em 1em;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.mgh-btn:hover {
  background-color: #349dcd;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.text-matter {
  transition: height 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 109.2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.clicked {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="mgh-common-header text-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease-in-cubic" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-delay="0">
    <h2>Standards & Compliances</h2>
    <p>Maintaining the highest of standards while conforming to regulations</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mgh-std-com">
    <div class="row text-center justify-content-sm-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-4 m-auto" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease-in-cubic" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-delay="0">
        <div class="mgh-std-com-sitem text-center">

          <div class="mgh-sc-box mb-3">
            <img src="assets/images/std-one.svg" alt="">
          </div>

          <h5>
            At MGH Healthcare, quality is a shared responsibility
          </h5>

          <p class="text-matter">Quality is the core value of MGH Healthcare that it ensures to be implemented at all levels. ADS’s management will ensure that this policy and relevant all legal and regulatory requirements are effectively communicated to the employees and other
            concerned personnel of quality assurance and operations to uphold company’s high standards of quality compliance at all times.</p>

          <a class="mgh-btn">read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-4 m-auto pt-5 pt-xl-0" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease-in-cubic" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-delay="1000">
        <div class="mgh-std-com-sitem text-center">

          <div class="mgh-sc-box mb-3">
            <img src="assets/images/std-two.svg" alt="">
          </div>

          <h5>
            Putting safety of products, customers and employees as
          </h5>

          <p class="text-matter">As a responsible business organization, MGH Healthcare operates its business according to the directives and guidelines of GxP, HSE and other local regulatory authorities. MGH Healthcare has stringent mandatory quality standards which ensure
            quality and safety of its products which conform to the relevant industry and regulatory standards.</p>

          <a class="mgh-btn">read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-4 m-auto pt-5 pt-xl-0" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease-in-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000" data-aos-delay="2000">
        <div class="mgh-std-com-sitem text-center">

          <div class="mgh-sc-box mb-3">
            <img src="assets/images/std-three.svg" alt="">
          </div>

          <h5>
            Building and maintaining a system to ensure quality and safety at all levels.
          </h5>

          <p class="text-matter">MGH Healthcare maintains a management system, which proactively and continuously develop its processes and systems to ensure quality and safety throughout the whole chain by providing training and resources. MGH Healthcare regularly evaluates
            and improves its performances using both internal and external measures.
          </p>

          <a class="mgh-btn">read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _“I want”_ is not a question. Please properly explain what your _problem_ with getting this done is.

Comment: Ok ! Question pattern has been update....

Comment: All you did now was change _two words_ of the phrasing, that is not an improvement at all. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```js
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("mgh-btn");
var myFunction = function() {
  this.classList.add("clicked");
  var element = document.getElementById("parentbg");
   element.classList.add("parentbgstyle");
   var element2 = document.getElementById("childbg");
   element2.classList.add("childbgstyle");
  this.previousElementSibling.classList.remove("text-matter");
  for (let i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    if (classname[i] != this) {
      classname[i].classList.remove("clicked");
    }
    if (classname[i].previousElementSibling != this.previousElementSibling) {
      classname[i].previousElementSibling.classList.add("text-matter");
    }
  }
};

for (let i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
  classname[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
}
```

```css
.mgh-std-com-area {
  margin: 80px 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* .mgh-std-com-sitem:hover {
  background: #eef9f9;
} */


/* .mgh-std-com-sitem:hover > .mgh-sc-box {
  background: #ffffff;
} */

.mgh-std-com-sitem .mgh-sc-box {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #eef9f9;
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem .mgh-sc-box img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem h5 {
  color: #2f2f2f;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: calc(22px + (30 - 22) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem h5::after {
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #349dcd;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.mgh-std-com-sitem p {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #2f2f2f;
  font-size: calc(16px + (22 - 16) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
}

.mgh-btn {
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #50c1c4, #349dcd);
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.9em 1em;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.mgh-btn:hover {
  background-color: #349dcd;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.text-matter {
  transition: height 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 109.2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.clicked {
  opacity: 0;
}
.parentbgstyle{
background-color: #EBFAF9;
}
.childbgstyle{
    background-color: #fff !important;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="mgh-common-header text-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease-in-cubic" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-delay="0">
    <h2>Standards & Compliances</h2>
    <p>Maintaining the highest of standards while conforming to regulations</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mgh-std-com">
    <div class="row text-center justify-content-sm-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-4 m-auto" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-easing="ease-in-cubic" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-delay="0">
        <div class="mgh-std-com-sitem text-center" id="parentbg">
 
          <div class="mgh-sc-box mb-3" id="childbg">
            <img src="assets/images/std-one.svg" alt="">
          </div>

          <h5>
            At MGH Healthcare, quality is a shared responsibility
          </h5>

          <p class="text-matter">Quality is the core value of MGH Healthcare that it ensures to be implemented at all levels. ADS’s management will ensure that this policy and relevant all legal and regulatory requirements are effectively communicated to the employees and other
            concerned personnel of quality assurance and operations to uphold company’s high standards of quality compliance at all times.</p>

          <a class="mgh-btn">read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro ! I have to need this background animations transition and text expanding animation for other two portion !